# Validate data for Ajax POST request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I have an order entry page and a corresponding ViewModel (simplified example):

```
public class OrderCreateViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Remark { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AddressCity { get; set; }
}
```

This model is used for the Create view:

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remark)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressCity)
    <input type="submit" value="Create order" name="saveButton" />
}
```

The Create action for the POST request in the controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save order in DB
        return RedirectToAction("Index");              
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The order (required fields and length of strings) gets validated on client side (using unobtrusive Javascript, jQuery validation) and on server side (`ModelState.IsValid`).

Now, I add a second button to the page which has the purpose to save the `Address` (`AddressCity` in the example) in a master table. This is supposed to happen with an Ajax POST request (using jQuery):

```
<input id="buttonAddAddress" type="button" value="Add address" />
```

A click event handler is hooked to this button which reads the content of input fields related to the address (only `AddressCity` in the example) and sends a POST request to the server:

```
$("#buttonAddAddress").click(function () {
    var address = JSON.stringify({
        City: $('#AddressCity').val()
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddAddress")',
        data: address,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ...
    });
});
```

The controller has a corresponding POST action for this request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAddress(Address address)
{
    // Create address in database
    return Json(true);
}
```

`Address` is a helper type:

```
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This code doesn't validate that `AddressCity` is required and must not be longer than 50 characters.

**Question: How can I add validation to this Ajax POST request - client side and server side validation as well?** I have no clue how to do it on client side. On server side I'd like to avoid the obvious trivial solution to repeat the meaning of the validation attributes (like `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.City) && address.City.Length <= 50) ...`, etc.) and leverage the existing validation attributes if that is possible at all.

Comment: I had a similar issue in that I had to handle validation errors through ajax calls and I followed http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/handling-validation-errors-on-ajax.html, however this is more related to returning partialviews vs json result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the server:

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and for the client, since you are using the AddressCity field, it will already have the same validation rule as the one applied from the main view model.

But since I guess that you will tell me that this is not DRY, well, OOP to the rescue:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and your main view model:

```
public class OrderCreateViewModel: AddressViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Remark { get; set; }
}
```

and your respective controller actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAddress(AddressViewModel address)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Slauma, yeap, then simply `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.

Comment: This looks very easy! Would it also work if `AddressViewModel` is a member of `OrderCreateViewModel` instead of inheritance?

Comment: The server side validation works with your approach, but the client side validation doesn't. Perhaps the reason is that the `input` element has `type="button"`, not `type="submit"`. (I don't know how exactly jquery validation works, possibly there is only an event handler hooked to input elements of type "submit".) But if we change the type to "submit" we get a post request to the Create action we don't want. Unfortunately we don't have time to solve the problem now. I accept your answer (server side is the more important part anyway), perhaps I'll create a followup question when we have time.